# Verify (Sql)TableAdapter Connection Before Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, tableadapter

My application collects data from an instrument (for a test trial) and stores it to a database.

How can I confirm my `(Sql)TableAdapter` can connect to the database before allowing data acquisition?

```
private void ARM_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        /* ??? */
        this.trialTableAdapter.CHECK_FOR_VALID_CONNECTION();
        /* ??? */

        this.myInstr.Setup(/*trial params, triggers, etc*/);
        this.myInstr.StartAcqNoWait();

    }
    catch
    {
        this.systemStatus_lbl.Text = "Error"; //TODO: more specific
        return;
    }

    this.systemStatus_lbl.Text = this.MSG_SYSTEM_READY_STR;
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following.  Feel free to suggest a "better" approach.

```
try
{
    this.trialTableAdapter.Connection.Open();
}

catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
{
    // TODO: Handle no DB connection
}
```